# how make device agitator with adb shell commands of python ppadb library?

Tags: python, shell, adb

I am trying to make the device shake or vibrate using adb shell commands sent from a python script. I use a LDPlayer Simulator. I have made the following attempts but I have not succeeded, I appreciate if anyone gives me ideas.

1. cicle of key event: KEYCODE_MOVE_END not fount for me

   ```
    for i in range(10):

        devX.shell("input keyevent 123")  # Tecla "End"

        devX.shell('sleep 0.05')

     devX.shell('sleep 1')

     devX.shell("input keyevent 123")
   ```
2. Key event 7

   ```
    devX.shell('input keyevent 7')
    devX.shell('sleep 1')
    devX.shell('input keyevent 7')
   ```

too trying with other keys.
the LDPLAYer simulator in which I am testing has a shortcut with ctrl+6 try to send the commands.

```
     devX.shell("input keyevent 113")  # Tecla Ctrl
     devX.shell("input keyevent 10")  # Tecla 6`
```

it does not work. I appreciate your ideas.